# How to connect two differents nodes types (structures) using pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, containers

I've been trying to figure out how to connect two different struct nodes using pointers. But I'm was not able to do that. See my draw bellow. At left I
have a "treeNode" with two pointers (below and right). The r-pointer connect to a different node called "branchNode" and for each "treeNode" I have five linked  "branchNodes".

Here is my problem: For example, if the "branchNode" 1 
doesn't exist, I wound like to create a temporary node
to insert it. But I don't know how to make this temporary node
receive the memory address of the "branchNode" 2.

[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZ28i.png)
\nSee my code bellow:

> main.cpp

```
#include "table.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    Table xxx;

    xxx.addTreeNodes(2,100);
    xxx.addTreeNodes(3,100);
    xxx.addTreeNodes(1,100);

    return 0;
```

> table.h

```
#ifndef TABLE_H_
#define TABLE_H_

class Table{
public:
    Table();
    int treeAddress(int newAddress, int dim);
    void addTreeNodes(int pos, int value);


private:
    struct treeNode {
    public: class branchNode;
        int address;
        treeNode* right;
        treeNode* below;
    };

    struct branchNode : public treeNode{
        int address;
        int data;
        branchNode* next;
    };

    treeNode* treeCurr;
    treeNode* treeTemp;
    treeNode* head;
    branchNode* branchHead;

    int branchDim;

};

#endif
```

> table.cpp

```
#include "table.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stddef.h>

Table::Table(){
    branchDim = 5;
    head = NULL;
    treeTemp = NULL;
    treeCurr = NULL;

    branchHead = NULL;

}

int Table::treeAddress(int Address, int dim){
    // This function is used to calculate the address
    // of treeNodes.
    float val = 1 + (int)((float)Address/(float)dim);
    if (Address % dim == 0){
        val--;
    }

    return val;
}

void Table::addTreeNodes(int pos, int value){
    // This part will create one treeNode in order, if
    // needed. Works fine, just skip this part.
    treeNode* tn = new treeNode;
    tn -> address = treeAddress(pos, branchDim);

    // if the table doesn't exist. Create one treeNode
    if (head == NULL){
        tn -> below = NULL;
        tn -> right = NULL;
        head = tn;
    }
    else{
        // insert treeNode before.
        if(tn -> address < head -> address){
            tn -> below = head;
            tn -> right = NULL;
            head = tn;
        }
        else{
            treeCurr = head;    
            treeTemp = head;
            while(treeCurr != NULL && treeCurr -> address < tn -> address){
                treeTemp = treeCurr;
                treeCurr = treeCurr -> below;
            }

            // insert treeNode on tail.
            if (treeCurr == NULL && tn -> address > treeTemp -> address){ 
                treeTemp -> below = tn;
                tn -> below = treeCurr;
                tn -> right = NULL;
            }
            else{ 
            // insert treeNode between two others nodes.
                if (tn -> address < treeCurr -> address){
                    treeTemp -> below = tn;
                    tn -> below = treeCurr;
                    tn -> right = NULL;
                }
                else{
                    delete[] tn;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // This part will create one branchNode. Here is the big problem...

    branchNode* bn = new branchNode;
    bn -> address = pos;

    treeCurr = head;
    int tPos = treeAddress(pos, branchDim);
    while(treeCurr != NULL && tPos != treeCurr -> address){
        treeCurr = treeCurr -> below;
    }
    //If the branch is empty.
    if (treeCurr -> right == NULL){
        treeCurr -> right = bn;
        bn -> next = NULL;
        bn -> address = pos;
    }

    else{
        //Here I wanna put the branchNode before the first branchNode.
        if (pos < (treeCurr -> right) -> address){
            branchHead = treeCurr -> right; // for some reason, I don't know why,
            bn -> next = branchHead;        // I can't do that!!!!!!!!!!.
            treeCurr -> right = bn;
            bn -> data = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "receive memory address of"? If you're talking about a pointer, then `treeNode* temp` is your answer.

Comment: @tedman, I meant that the temporary node will point to the last branchNode created. I can create a temporary node using treeNode *, but I can not insert a branchNode like this.

Comment: Why can't you insert a node like that? I think your understanding of what pointers are needs to be shored up a little with some more experimentation and research.

Comment: @Rabbid76, Thanks for the tip. I'll research more about it!

Comment: @tadman Yes, I need to learn more. The problem is: inserting a node like that, maybe at some point I'll have to convert it and I do not know how to do this yet. Rabbid76 gave me one suggestion, I'm checking this out.

Comment: This doesn't look like your typical tree implementation. It's normally not necessary for a tree node to have two flavours, so casting is typically not an issue. Since your one `struct` inherits from the other, you actually have two `address` properties, one's shadowing the other. It's also peculiar that you have a hybrid linked-list and tree structure. On most occasions you'd stick with one approach, not both.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there exist only one "treeNode" and some "branchNode" for simplicity. I was able to point correctly to another type of node, following the hint of @Rabbid76 (thanks!). Maybe there's another way, but I'm already happy.

> main.cpp

```
#include "table.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    Table xxx;

    xxx.addTreeNodes(5,100);
    xxx.addTreeNodes(3,140);
    xxx.addTreeNodes(2,20);

    xxx.print();

    return 0;
}
```

> table.h

```
#ifndef TABLE_H_
#define TABLE_H_

class Table{
public:
    Table();
    void addTreeNodes(int pos, int value);
    void print();

private:
    struct treeNode {
    public: class branchNode;
        treeNode* right;
        treeNode* below;
    };

    struct branchNode : public treeNode{
        int address;
        int data;
        branchNode* next;
    };

    branchNode* branchCurr;
    treeNode* head;
    treeNode* tn;
};

#endif
```

> table.cpp

```
#include "table.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stddef.h>

Table::Table(){
    head = NULL;
    branchCurr = NULL;
    tn = new treeNode;
}

void Table::addTreeNodes(int pos, int value){

    branchNode* bn = new branchNode;
    bn -> address = pos;
    bn -> data = value; 

    tn -> below = NULL;

    if (head == NULL){
        head = tn;
        bn -> next = NULL;
        tn -> right = bn;
    }           
    else{
        if (pos < ((branchNode*)head -> right) -> address){
            branchCurr = (branchNode*)head -> right;
            bn -> address = pos;
            bn -> data = value;
            tn -> right = bn;
            bn -> next = branchCurr;
        }
        else{
            delete[] bn;
        }
    }
}

void Table::print(){
    branchCurr = (branchNode*)head -> right;            
    while(branchCurr != NULL){
        std::cout << "address: " << branchCurr -> address 
                  << ", stored value: " << branchCurr -> data <<  std::endl;
        branchCurr = branchCurr -> next;
    }
}
```